# diagram tool for the design of ros2 packages

Tags: ros, ros2, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I need to develop some ROS2 packages for my robot. Before writing each package, I want to draw a diagram for the package relations (e.g. the message, the class calling between them), like a class diagram?

Is there a name for this diagram and is there any tool for this?

The final diagram may look like rqt_graph. But it is designed before every package is prepared.

There seems to be a "package diagram" in starUML. But I'm not sure whether this "package diagram" satisfies .

Thanks for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410068/diagram-tool-for-the-design-of-ros2-packages/) by [xibeisiber](https://answers.ros.org/users/54937/xibeisiber/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2022-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using [draw.io,](https://app.diagrams.net/) it is free. It provides all the basic structure you required for creating graphs, class, and functions.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2022-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0